# Local development environment for osTicket

Tags: email, vagrant, lamp, osticket

I am developing custom features for osTicket and I need to setup a mail system that sends emails, locally, and can simulate several email inboxes.

My local development setup is vagrant with ubuntu precise 64. I already have the LAMP stack running.

osTicket needs to send emails (only internally) and needs to have mailboxes (osticket reads and processes incoming mail on selected mailboxes).

I installed postfix, but could not get it to work.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I installed osTicket for my company. It can allow you to setup SMTP, which can use your Gmail account to send email. It is simple to setup.
The only thing to keep in mind is you need to use "Allow less secure apps to access your account". See: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en for more information.

Configure ssl://smtp.gmail.com as your SMTP address and port 465 as your SMTP port. Even if you are not using Gmail, you still have to put "ssl://" before your SMTP host name.